# Calculate oblique sides to get a wanted result after transform

Tags: canvas, drawing, 2d, game-physics, isometric

I've written a drawing function for creating isometric planes.
The function accepts the following parameters.

- `widthIso` - the isometric (oblique) side width of the plane.
- `heightIso` - the isometric height of the plane.
- `imgObj` - an object containing a pattern image (not important in this question)

I've made a JSFiddle to make it clearer: https://jsfiddle.net/Le45oo71/10/

My `draw` function creates a canvas, so I can use that canvas to draw it on the main canvas. (It's prerendering).

The function does the following:

- Create an offscreen canvas.
- Calculate and set the canvas size.
- Transform the context to isometric projection.
- Draw a rectangle filled with the image from the `imgObj`

Of course, due to the transformations on the context, it's a little bit naive to expect that the oblique sides of the isometric plane have exactly the wanted lengths.
I tried a lot, but I can't figure out how to calculate a number so, that after the transfomations, the resulting plane has the wanted side lengths.

I expect that when the rectangle is drawn, the sides of the flat (not-transformed) rectangle must be a little bit longer. So that after the transformation, the plane sides have the wanted length.

Answer (score 1):

## Transform Matrix

Easy answer at the bottom. If you want to know how then read the rest.

**Set transform and the crazy abc's**

You can use `ctx.setTransform(a, b, c, d, e, f);` to solve this. Using it rather than `ctx.transform`, `ctx.rotate`, `ctx.scale`, or `ctx.translate` means you do not have to worry about any previous transforms as it replaces the existing transform rather than multiplying the existing transform.

The magic arguments can be best understood as the direction and scale of the x and y axis and the screen coordinate of the origin.

All the values relate to pixels coordinates. The axis describe the direction and size of a single pixel, a,b for the top of a pixel and c,d for the left side. e,f is the coordinate on the screen where the transformed coordinate 0,0 will appear, called the origin.

By default a pixel is one pixel across `a = 1`, and zero pixels down `b = 0`. The pixel is zero pixels across `c = 0` and one pixel down `d = 1`. The origin is at the top left `e = 0`, `f = 0`;

Thus to set the default transform `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);`

Let's call the variables something more meaningful. They are vectors and for the x axis it has a x and y component `a = xAX` (**x** **A**xis **Y** component) and `b = xAY` ( **x** **A**xis **Y** component ). Same for the y axis `c = yAX` and `d = yAY`. (I prefer `xAx`,`xAy`,`yAx`,`yAy` a slight break from convention) and for origin `ox`, `oy`

Thus `ctx.setTransform(xAx, xAy, yAx, yAy, ox, oy)` making the whole thing slightly clearer (less mud like).

The two axis are independent and can point in any direction and be any length this allows us to create isometric projections and more. The scale is determined by the length of the axis. The x scale is the length of the x axis and the y scale is the length of the y axis.

To create a vector for an axis we use cos and sin as they return the x and y component of an angle. So if we want the x axis to be a 45 deg (Math.PI / 4 in radians) we can get the vector via

```
var direction = Math.PI/4; // 45 deg down and right
var xAx = Math.cos(direction);
var xAy = Math.sin(direction);
```

If we want the y axis at 135 deg (Math.PI * (3/4) radians)

```
var direction = Math.PI * (3/4); // 135 deg down and left
var yAx = Math.cos(direction);
var yAy = Math.sin(direction);
```

Cos and sin alway create a unit vector ( a vector that is 1 unit long) that means that the scale of the vectors is 1 (effectively no scale)

To change the scale of a vector you multiply both the x and y components. So adding to the above let's scale both axis.

```
var scale = 2; // zoom by 2
direction = Math.PI/4; // 45 deg down and right
xAx = Math.cos(direction) * scale;
xAy = Math.sin(direction) * scale;
direction = Math.PI * (3/4); // 135 deg down and left
yAx = Math.cos(direction) * scale;
yAy = Math.sin(direction) * scale;
```

Now we can set the origin to the center of the canvas

```
var ox = ctx.canvas.width/2;
var oy = ctx.canvas.height/2;
```

So to use that to create the transform

```
ctx.setTransform(xAx, xAy, yAx, yAy, ox, oy); // set the transform
ctx.strokeRect(0,0,20,10); // draws a rectangle 40 pixels ( scale 2) at 45 deg
                           // and 20 pixels at 135 deg centered on the canvas
```

Hopefully you can see how simple this is.

**The Answer**

If you have an image that needs to be scaled so that the sides are of a required size we need to find the scale. Say the image is 100 pixel in width and we need to display it at 300 pixels. To get the scale divide the screen size by the image size `300/100 = 3` the scale is 3.

The scale is independent of the axis direction.

We can put this all together as a function that takes the angles of the x, and y axis, the size of the image width and height, the display width and height and the location of the origin. Then we calculate the scale, create the axis and set the transform

```
function createTransform(angX, angY, imgWidth, imgHeight, displayWidth, displayHeight, originX, originY){
    var scaleX = displayWidth / imgWidth;  // get x scale
    var scaleY = displayHeight / imgHeight;  // get y scale
    // create the x axis
    var xAx = Math.cos(angX) * scaleX;
    var xAy = Math.sin(angX) * scaleX;
    // create the y axis
    var yAx = Math.cos(angY) * scaleY;
    var yAy = Math.sin(angY) * scaleY;
    // set the transform
    ctx.setTransform(xAx, xAy, yAx, yAy, originX, originY);
}
```

And now you can draw the image

```
// assume image is a loaded image
// axis at 45 and 135 deg make the display width and height 200,300 at the canvas center
createTransform(Math.PI / 4, Math.PI * (3 / 4), image.width, image.height, 200, 300, ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2)
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0); // drawn to fit requirements.
```

**Copy and Paste easy answer**

The above does not match what you want as you are using a pattern and the angle are a little different but if I just did the solution for you you would not get much out of it except for an immediate cut and paste solution to the problem.

```
function draw(widthIso, heightIso, imgObj) {
    // rather than the messing around with the and rotations hand code the axis 
    // x axis
    var xAx = 1;
    var xAy = 0.5; 

    // y axis
    var yAx = -1;
    var yAy = 0.5; 

    // need the length of the axis so we can calculate a scale adjustment
    var scaleX = Math.sqrt(xAx * xAx + xAy * xAy); // pythagoras to get the length of x axis
    var scaleY = Math.sqrt(yAx * yAx + yAy * yAy); // pythagoras to get the length of y axis

    // now we know how big a pixel is in isometric projection
    // assuming you don't want to change the image pixel size from what you have in the fiddle 
    // I will workout the draw size

    var drawWidth = widthIso / scaleX;
    var drawHeight = heightIso / scaleY;

    // get the width as sum of the product of axis x & y,  x components
    var canvasWidth = xAx * widthIso + yAx * heightIso;

    // get the width as sum of the product of axis x & y,  y components
    var canvasHeight = xAy * widthIso + yAy * heightIso;

    // create the canvas rounding up for size so we don't lose any pixels
    var ca = document.createElement('canvas');
    ca.width = Math.ceil(canvasWidth);
    ca.height = Math.ceil(canvasHeight);
    var ctx = ca.getContext('2d');

    // now get the origin 
    var originY = 0; // always at the top
    var originX = yAx * heightIso; // in by x component of height

    // now just set the transform
    ctx.setTransform(xAx, xAy, yAx, yAy, originX, originY);

    // create pattern
    var pattern = ctx.createPattern(imgObj.img, 'repeat');
    ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
    // draw with the corrected width and height
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, drawWidth, drawHeight);
    // return the canvas image
    return {canvas: ca, ctx: ctx, toLeft: originX};
}
```

And that is done. Pixel perfect don't forget to round up when creating canvas images or you may lose a pixel on the edges

This is the code that I tested it with. Moved your red and blue lines to the center and made them exactly 200 and 300 pixels long.

```
// to visualise with red and blue lines.
 var x  = Math.cos(Math.atan2(0.5,-1))*150 + 230;
 var y  = Math.sin(Math.atan2(0.5,-1))*150 + 50;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x, y); // no guessing
ctx.lineTo(x + Math.cos(Math.atan2(0.5,1))*200, y + Math.sin(Math.atan2(0.5,1))*200); // 
ctx.stroke();

 var x  = Math.cos(Math.atan2(0.5,1))*100 + 230;
 var y  = Math.sin(Math.atan2(0.5,1))*100 + 50;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x, y); // 
ctx.lineTo(x + Math.cos(Math.atan2(0.5,-1))*300, y + Math.sin(Math.atan2(0.5,-1))*300); // 
ctx.stroke();
```